# Не могу обновить состояние значениями, которые зависят от текущего состояния React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, useeffect

Есть компонент switch. Он работает чуть чуть неправильно. Тоесть в первый раз при нажатии как бы его state не меняется, а потом в другие разы всё получается. Я понял что это как то связано с обновлением состояния значениями, которые зависят от текущего состояния. Даже понял что это надо как то исправлять с useEffect но не понял как..

Нашёд решение только к классовым компонентам когда передавали функцию вместо объекта в setState() но мне нужно решить проблему на функциональном компоненте

Пожалуйста помогите новичку...

```
export default function Profile(props) {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const [modalAbout, setModalAbout] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isEnabled) {
        setIsEnabled(true)
        props.updateDataEvent(isEnabled)    
    }
  }, [props,isEnabled]) 
   
  //bla bla bla

}
```

всё равно передаёт false колбэк функцию

Это я передаю данные родителю с props.updateDataEvent если чё...

Comment: Приведите **прямо в вопросе** ваш код (править вопрос можно, нажав кнопку править).

Comment: Оно не может передать в `props.updateDataEvent(isEnabled)` значение false, т.к. в ваш if никогда не попадете, т.к. isEnabled = false. А если попадете, то можете зациклить рендер. И зачем при значении isEnabled = true делать его еще раз true?